# Connect to Enterprise GitHub from Terraform cloud function

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, terraform, github-enterprise

I am trying to create a Google Cloud function through Terraform. The source code for the function is in Enterprise GitHub. https://github.xyz.com/cf

The Terraform code is as below:

```
resource "google_cloudfunctions_function" "cfcluster" {
  name        = "cfcluster1"
  project = "${var.project_id}"
  region  = "us-central1"

  
  runtime     = "python39"

  source_repository  {
//url="https://github.xyz.com/cf" #is this possible?
}
```

Is it possible to connect to Enterprise GitHub from Google CloudFunction in Terraform? How can I achieve it?

### Note

I don't want to connect to cloud-source repository from Terraform.

Comment: User1403505, please read these general posting tips: (1) run a spelling checker before you submit your questions; (2) observe the case of words - software names like Terraform take a capital, as do brands like Google; (3) be conscious of the difference between a product like Git and a command like `git`; (4) do not beg and plead; (5) use action-oriented statements like "How can I do X" and "How to achieve X". Ask specific and focussed questions, not [please help me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).

Comment: You'll find you'll have an easier time of it here if you can comply with some basic guidelines. You've received downvotes before, and that may happen less often if you can improve your posting quality.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can pull data from a GitHub repository directly. What you can do is to mirror it to your project's Cloud Repository, and then you can use the data within the Google Cloud Platform as you wish. Here you can find a document on how to mirror your GitHub Repository [1].

You can also take a look at this tutorial [2], here you can find the complete steps to deploy an application in Google Cloud Platform from a Github Repository.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/source-repositories/docs/mirroring-a-github-repository

[2] https://medium.com/swlh/deploying-github-repository-to-google-cloud-platform-997d296547e6